# @Transactional methods called inside TransactionTemplate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I've a complex task in my app that make intensive use of transactionTemplate. I've only a problem when I do this:

```
transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
  component1.method1();
  .....
  //COMMIT OF THE TRANSACTION
}
```

where component1 is something like this:

```
@Component
public class Component1{
   public boolean method1(){
       component2.method2();
       ....
       ....
```

where component2 is something like this:

```
@Transactional
public interface Component2 extends JpaRepository<Impostazione, Long>
    @Query(value = "FROM Settings WHERE key=?")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Impostazione method2(String key);
```

All works fine but adding this on the bean that is persisted:

```
@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
private void printLog(){
   log.debug("*******UPDATE/PERSIST**********");
```

I see that Hibernate (I'm using it) update/persist entity BEFORE I go out from the code of transactionTemplate, so BEFORE the transaction is committed.

Now, I'm quite sure that removing the @Trasactional annotation from my method all should works but I can't do this because I'm reusing services that I'm using also in others part of my application.
I think is unwise replicate the code and have service with @Transactional and service without it with the same implementation.

Hoping in a enlightening response. Thanks!

-----EDIT---------
Finally also removing @Transactional from Component2 the problem still persist. Interesting...

Comment: Do removing `@Transactional` actually changes the behavior?

Comment: PrePersist doesn't mean PreCommit. Hibernate doesn't always wait until the end of a transaction to persist.

Comment: @JBNizet, so is normal it enters in the method several times before the commit? There is no warranty the method is called only one time after update/commit?

Comment: Yes. PrePersist annotated methods are called before the entity is persisted to the database. Not before the transaction is committed.

Comment: In your opinion there is a smart way to intercept the commit of the transaction? My goal is to make some changes in the bean before it is committed. But if @PreUpdate invoke this methods several times this is quite expensive in my case. Thanks

Comment: A bean is not committed. A transaction is committed. When the transaction commits, all the beans have already been saved to the database.

Comment: If you are already using `TransactionTemplate` you might find `TransactionSynchronizationManager` useful (you can register a callback for the commit phase).